# Fonts and Luma Icons not loading in Magento 2.4.6 after implementing Cloudfront CDN

Tags: luma-theme, magento2.4.6, cloudfront-cdn

My site was working fine before implementing CDN. However, after implementing CloudFront CDN, only fonts(woff2) and Luma Icons are not working. All other static and media content are loading perfectly fine. I'm attaching my Cloudfront Settings and HTACCESS files of Static folder.

I'm seeing the following error in both Chrome and Firefox
[image]

AWS CloudFront General Settings
[image]

AWS CloudFront Origin Settings
[image]

AWS CloudFront Bheaviour Settings
[image]

And, my static folder htaccess has following code

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json)$>
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
      Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "604800"
      Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Host, Content-Type, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With"
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
       Header append Cache-Control no-store
   </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

If it matters, I also use Varnish and changed Apache2 ports to 8080.
SSL certificates used in Cloudfront are created by AWS itself and
main domain SSL is from Let's Encrypt.

**Also, why is it trying to download fonts and icons files twice?**

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine which assets are served through CDN, you can navigate to the "Behavior" section within your distribution settings. Here, you have the ability to selectively add or exclude specific assets based on your needs. This provides a streamlined approach to managing your assets and ensures that they are being served efficiently through the CDN.